# @RequestBody @Valid: Content type not supported

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I got an exception while using those two annotations in my pet spring-boot app:

> Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/home/filter/edit")
public String processUpdateFilterForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserMatchSearchingFilterDTO userMatchSearchingFilterDTO,
                                      BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new ValidationException(bindingResult.toString());
    }
    userService.update(userMatchSearchingFilterDTO);
    return REDIRECT_TO_HOME;
}
```

Page code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <h2>Edit filter</h2>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Minimum Age</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="number" id="ageMin" name="ageMin" value="27"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <br>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Update filter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I use a spring validation without writing my own validators? How do I need to change my page or controller? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`. You are sending request parameters from a form, not sending a request body in the form of JSON or XML. The latter needs `@RequestBody` the first needs `@ModelAttribute`. A form uses data-binding, use a body uses serialization.

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed my controller(look to the post please) but it still has no errors... I uses a 'javax.validation.constraints.@Max'.
UPD. It updates my data but the validation does not work

Comment: Nice that you have an annotation, but without an actual implementation on the classpath it doesn't do anything. Make sure that `spring-boot-starter-validation` is on your classpath (and what you are asking now is a different question actually!).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you!!! You are right, I added only validation api without implementation.